# Android GridLayout not showing

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to recreate the game 2048.

When I'm clicking on the button "New Game", I start a new intent with the PlayActivity. The button starts the activity, but when the view shows, the grid layout is not visible...

The view is a textview and then the GridLayout (which is custom, because I have to populate it with custom tiles)...

The code:

PlayActivity.java

```
public class PlayActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    }  
}
```

activity_play.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/score"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"/>

    <com.charlotteerpels.oefening1.Board
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.charlotteerpels.oefening1.Board>
</LinearLayout>
```

Board.java

```
public class Board extends GridLayout {

    Card[][] cardBoard;
    private int cardHeight;
    private int cardWidth;

    public void initBoard(Context context) {
        this.setColumnCount(4);
        this.setRowCount(4);
        this.cardBoard = new Card[4][4];
        calculateCardSpecs(context);
        populateBoard();
    }

    private void calculateCardSpecs(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
        this.cardWidth = width/4;
        this.cardHeight = this.cardWidth;
    }

    private void populateBoard() {
        int tilesWithNumber = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                Card card = new Card(getContext());

                if(random.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                    if(tilesWithNumber<2) {
                        card.setTextVisible();
                        tilesWithNumber++;
                    }
                }

                cardBoard[i][j] = card;
            }
        }
        addCardsToView();
    }

    private void addCardsToView() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                Card card = cardBoard[i][j];
                addView(card, cardWidth, cardHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    public Board(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initBoard(context);
    }

    public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initBoard(context);
    }

    public Board(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initBoard(context);
    }

}
```

Card.java

```
public class Card extends FrameLayout {

    Random randomGenerator;
    private int number;
    Resources res = getResources();
    private TextView lblNumber;

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    private void initCard(Context context) {
        lblNumber = new TextView(context);
        lblNumber.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.light_brown));

        randomGenerator = new Random();
        int r = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);

        if(r == 0)
            this.number = 2;
        else
            this.number = 4;
    }

    public void setTextVisible() {
        lblNumber.setText(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCard(context);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initCard(context);
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initCard(context);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You aren't adding the text view to the Card, you are only creating it

Comment: Omg thank that worked! Thank you! I still need to do some UI changes, because the Cards don't have some space between them, but I'll figure that out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: RobVoisey found the answer, I created the TextView lblNumber in the class Card, but I didn't added it to the Card...

So in the class Card in the method initCard, I added after the if/else the textView lblNumber to the Card layout:

```
private void initCard(Context context) {
    lblNumber = new TextView(context);
    lblNumber.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.light_brown));

    randomGenerator = new Random();
    int r = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);

    if(r == 0)
        this.number = 2;
    else
        this.number = 4;

    addView(lblNumber);
}
```